# Matching first four words with regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match the first 4 words in the input string.

My pattern: `([\w\’\s{3}])+`

My content: `test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7`

I want to get: `test1 test2 test3 test4`

All alphabetic characters and there are max 3 spaces.

Comment: You just need [`\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/vS3mA8/1) and a method to match globally.

Comment: it's not enough for that :/

Comment: Prove it is not, I [have](https://regex101.com/r/vS3mA8/1). For now, the question is way too unclear.

Comment: i can see.. but i'm not sure you understand what i want. I want all of "test1 test2 test3 test4" like that.I don't want separately.

Comment: `^([\w\']+\s){0,3}[\w\']+`

Comment: Like [`\w+(?:\s+\w+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/vS3mA8/2)? Unless you explain what you are doing and specify the environment  you are working in, the question is unclear.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/vS3mA8/3 - @WiktorStribiżew not working :/

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/vS3mA8/4 - @shawnt00 not working :/

Comment: @Serhat: Why did you ruin the regex I suggested? It must be [`\w+(?:\s+\w+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/vS3mA8/5). Do not put the whole pattern into a character class. "Not working" does not tell us anything  - how *must* it work then?

Comment: @Serhat My interpretation is that you want (up to) the first four words. I won't be surprised if Wiktor can improve my expression but i do believe it's working.

Comment: @shawnt00: I'd avoid adding the `'` to the `+`-quantified character class to avoid match `'''''''' '''''''' ''''''`.

Comment: Okay i'll try to explain. My english is not better than you. Sorry about that. For example this is an content "Lorem  (for example two spaces.)ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit." . I just wanna get that same words of first 4 words. Because i will search on google after found. I want to learn There is an result with same words. and Wiktor really your regex is not working. i tried. and shawnt00 your code is working is probably. it seems work on regex101.com but it does not work on php i guess it's my problem. thanks for help both of you.

Comment: At last: PHP. The first 4 words. See http://ideone.com/FPCosu

Comment: i guess it's enough thanks again it's working :)

Comment: Yeah, but perhaps, you could just use `explode(" ", $s)`, and then just take the first 4 elements and imlode'd them back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could perhaps just use `explode(" ", $s)`, and then take the first 4 elements and `imlode` them back, a fixed regex solution is

```
$re = '~(?:[\w\']+\s+){3}[\w\']+~'; 
$str = "Lorem  ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."; 
preg_match($re, $str, $match);
echo $match[0];               // => Lorem  ipsum dolor sit
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/FPCosu) and here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pN7wN6/1).

The `preg_match` finds the first occurrence of 4 words matched with

- `(?:[\w\']+\s+){3}` - 3 sequences of 1+ word chars or `'` symbol followed with 1+ whitespaces
- `[\w\']+` - 1+ word or `'` chars.